# Color of the navigation bar in beamer (theme Goettingen)

Tags: beamer, color, navigation

How can I change the color of the navigation bar in beamer? I am using "**Goettingen**" theme. I tried several changes, but that did not work...

[image]

CODE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is just a short example
    \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
    \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Background information}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Beamer offers a lot of functions to create nice slides using \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}
    This style uses the following default styles:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item split
      \item whale
      \item rounded
      \item orchid
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{The important things}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The important things}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This just shows the effect of the style
    \item It is not a Beamer tutorial
    \item Read the Beamer manual for more help
    \item Contact me only concerning the style file
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Analysis of the work}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Analysis of the work}

  When you know how to work with the Beamer package it is easy to use.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy to use
    \item Good results
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I remember you can use `outer color theme`. They are color themes for  headline, footline, and sidebar. Another way is changing the templates, information about this, is in beamer guide by Till Tantau

Answer (score 6):

I am unsure which colors of the different navigation components you want to change, so let me go through some of them.

- The color of the *navigation symbols* can be changed using:

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red, bg=green}
  ```
- The color of the *navigation panel* you can change by putting

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
  ```

  *before* `\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}`. Notice, however, that the colour will still be washed out, fading from top to bottom.
- You can change the color of the *titles* in the navigation bar using

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=yellow,bg=blue}
  \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=red,bg=black}
  ```

  The `secondary` colors are the ones currently active.

I am not advocating these particular choices, especially since this is what they do:

[image]

Here is the code that produced this image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}
\usepackage{color}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}

\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red, bg=green}

\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=yellow,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=red,bg=black}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Outline}\tableofcontents \end{frame}

  \section{Introduction}\begin{frame}{Introduction}\end{frame}

  \section{Background}\begin{frame}{Background}\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Finally, it is possible to have more than one color in the side bar by placing

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}%
                  [vertical shading][top=green,bottom=blue]
\makeatother
```

*after* you have set the color them. Splicing this into the MWE above yields:

[image]

Again, pretty as they may be, I don't recommend any of these colors.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to change anything from a `beamer` theme I'd suggest to take a look at original theme definition file (`beamerthemeGoettingen.sty` in this case). There you'll see what other themes (innr, outer, font, ...) are used and which templates do you need to change.

Goettingen theme file is only 34 lines long and only load and customizes `side bar` outer theme. At the end of the file you'll find

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading]    
[top=structure.fg!25,bottom=structure.fg!10]
```

which means that the color for sidebar is `structure`. So if you want to change it, something like

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
```

as [Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246326/1952) suggested would do it. But a lot of beamer theme elements are based in `structure` color, so if you change it, everything else will do it. As an example, look at navigator symbols in Andrew's answer figures. They are red because `structure` was changed.

If I just wanted to change only sidebar background color, I'd insert

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading][top=red!25,bottom=red!10]
\makeatother
```

in my preamble. The result would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading][top=red!25,bottom=red!10]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is just a short example
    \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
    \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Background information}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Beamer offers a lot of functions to create nice slides using \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}
    This style uses the following default styles:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item split
      \item whale
      \item rounded
      \item orchid
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{The important things}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The important things}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This just shows the effect of the style
    \item It is not a Beamer tutorial
    \item Read the Beamer manual for more help
    \item Contact me only concerning the style file
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Analysis of the work}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Analysis of the work}

  When you know how to work with the Beamer package it is easy to use.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy to use
    \item Good results
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the navigation symbols are red because I made them that way using `\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red, bg=green}`. Of course, you are right as without this they would be pale red in my example. For what it's worth, I referred to the  `sidebar canvas` at the end of my post.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you changed them, but even without doing it, if you change `structure` color, navigator symbols, titles, ... will also change. i think that unless you know what's affected by `structure` color, it's better not to touch it.